# Persistent resources in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, persistent

First, this may not be the best title, but it seems to make sense at this time.

What I'm looking at is loading a resource which should live for the life of the web app. There may be some provisioning at a later point for a manual refresh, but currently that is not the case.

We have a complex permission structure which resides in the database for multiple reasons. I do not want to incur the overhead of retrieving this for each page load, thus I want it to reside in memory. My first instinct is to create a singleton which I load this into and use it whenever needed to lookup a permission. I understand the hesitance towards singletons and wonder if that is a poor approach.

I do not want to go down the route of yaml or another storage mechanism, the permissions must reside in the DB for other dependencies. That said, in Rails, what would be the most appropriate way to efficiently load and read the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use of the cache

```
permissions = Rails.cache.fetch( 'permissions' ) do
  # Permissions don't exist yet, perform long operation and load from DB
  load_permissions_from_db
end
```

More details [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: Being a rails newcomer I had not seen this, but I like how it looks. I'll give this a shot, hopefully it will work for my needs.

Comment: NP, I had to go through the same learning curve. Definitely check out http://railscasts.com/ for intros to many of the rails concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you mean but i think there are a few ways you could go

- caching (e.g. `caches_page :page` or `caches_action :action` in the controller )
- or possibly storing something in a cookie/ session data, of course i don't totally understand the nature of this data so I don't Know what would work better, if at all